# Count rows that are displayed in a gridview on textchanged/keyup using javascript (ASP)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am displaying rows that are filtered through textchanged using javascript. But I want to count the rows of a gridview that are filtered from textbox. So this is my code on displaying rows that are filtered through textchanged(onkeyup)

Javascript code:

```
function Search_gridUser(strKey)
    {
        var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var tblData = document.getElementById('<%=gridData.ClientID %>');

        for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) 
        {
            rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
            var styleDisplay = 'none';
            for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) 
            {
                if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0) {
                    styleDisplay = '';
                }
                else {
                    styleDisplay = 'none';
                    break;
                }
            }
            tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Show `total` how ever you want.

```
function Search_gridUser(strKey)
{
    var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var tblData = document.getElementById('<%=gridData.ClientID %>');
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) 
    {
        rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
        var styleDisplay = 'none';
        for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) 
        {
            if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0) {
                styleDisplay = '';
            }
            else {
                styleDisplay = 'none';
                total++;
                break;
            }
        }
        tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
    }
}
```